# lib32stdc++6 package depends on gcc base but my installed version is newer

Tags: apt

I am trying to build an android app on Ubuntu 14.04 using eclipse juno and android adt bundle. Now when i try to run my application it shows the error regarding adb. Now in order to resolve that i need to install 32 bit libraries and in those libraries one of them is `libstdc++6`. When i type the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
```

It shows the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   lib32stdc++6 : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 is to be installed
                 Depends: lib32gcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Edit:

The output of the command:

```
     sudo apt-cache policy lib32stdc++6 gcc-4.8-base lib32gcc1
```

is as following:

```
lib32stdc++6:
        Installed: (none)
        Candidate: 4.8.2-19ubuntu1
       Version table:
        4.8.2-19ubuntu1 0
           500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
gcc-4.8-base:
      Installed: 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04
      Candidate: 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04
      Version table:
      *** 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 0
             100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
         4.8.2-19ubuntu1 0
             500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
 lib32gcc1:
    Installed: (none)
    Candidate: 1:4.9-20140406-0ubuntu1
    Version table:
       1:4.9-20140406-0ubuntu1 0
         500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have installed `gcc-4.8-base 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04` by a (in the meantime deleted) PPA or via a deb file. As the version of this package is higher than the requested version (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1), the package `libstdc++6` is not installed. Therefore force the installation of official version via a downgrade:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8-base=4.8.2-19ubuntu1
```

---

But this version is not the latest available version. Therefore check if you have enabled the `trusty-updates` repository.

1. Start <kbd>Software & Updates</kbd>
2. Select the tab <kbd>Updates</kbd>
3. Select <kbd>Recommended updates (trusty-updates)</kbd> (In my screenshot it's vivid-updates, but that's just an example)

   [image]

   And click <kbd>Close</kbd>
4. Click <kbd>Reload</kbd> in this dialog

   [image]
5. Now upgrade your system (again **;)**)

   ```
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   ```
6. And install

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
   ```

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 indicator-bluetooth : Depends: unity-control-center but it is not going to be installed or    gnome-control-center but it is not going to be installed or       ubuntu-system-settings but it is not going to be installed
 libdee-1.0-4 : Depends: libicu52 (>= 52~m1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 system-image-dbus : Depends: system-image-common (= 2.2-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

Comment: This is what i am getting when i tried to force install..

Comment: Okay,,, why do you say that ??

Comment: Okay.. Now you have me totally scared. What should be done? And is there anything that can be done at this point??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28902/discussion-between-tejvir-and-a-b).

Comment: As you're a reputation 11 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of the answer, which means "yes, this answer is valid"! ;-)

Comment: Yeah sure i will do that. 

Comment: sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libstdc++6 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: @Tejvir Have you enabled the trusty-updates repositories?

Comment: Hey thank you so much man.. Its working now.. And all my issues on eclipse regarding ADT bundle as well are now solved. Thanks to you..

Comment: Software & Updates section did the trick for me when trying to get the Android SDK working on 64 bit Ubuntu