# unmet dependencies while installing ns-allinone2.29.2 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, dependencies

I'm installing `ns2-allinone-2.29.2` (not the latest, I needed this to test st) on Ubuntu 14.04 and got the above problem. Even though the dependencies are installed it cannot recognize it. Please help! I love Linux!!!

```
asrat@asrat-B85M-D3H:~$ **sudo apt-get -f install gcc-4.8 libstdc++-4.8-dev**
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gcc-4.8 is already the newest version.
gcc-4.8 set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libstdc++-4.8-dev : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 is to be installed
                     Depends: libgcc-4.8-dev (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

asrat@asrat-B85M-D3H:~$ **sudo apt-get -f install gcc-4.8-base libgcc-4.8-dev**
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libgcc-4.8-dev is already the newest version.
gcc-4.8-base is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

asrat@asrat-B85M-D3H:~$ **sudo apt-get -f install gcc-4.8 libstdc++-4.8-dev**
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gcc-4.8 is already the newest version.
gcc-4.8 set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libstdc++-4.8-dev : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 is to be installed
                     Depends: libgcc-4.8-dev (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Add the output of `apt-cache policy libgcc-4.8-dev` and `apt-cache policy gcc-4.8-base`

Comment: asrat@asrat-B85M-D3H:~$ sudo apt-cache policy libgcc-4.8-dev
libgcc-4.8-dev:
  Installed: 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04
  Candidate: 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04
  Version table:
 *** 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.8.2-19ubuntu1 0
        500 ftp://ftp.cesca.cat/ubuntu/archieve/ trusty/main amd64 Packages

Comment: asrat@asrat-B85M-D3H:~$ sudo apt-cache policy gcc-4.8-base 
gcc-4.8-base:
  Installed: 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04
  Candidate: 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04
  Version table:
 *** 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.8.2-19ubuntu1 0
        500 ftp://ftp.cesca.cat/ubuntu/archieve/ trusty/main amd64 Packages

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/671791/lib32stdc6-package-depends-on-gcc-base-but-my-installed-version-is-newer

Comment: my problem is solved based on http://askubuntu.com/questions/671791/lib32stdc6-package-depends-on-gcc-base-but-my-installed-version-is-newer